# Module (album) could not be initialized zf2 tutorial

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am working through the zend framework 2 tutorial application. I have set up my Album Module directory as follows:

[image]

I am running into an error when I start my MAMP server, `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Album) could not be initialized.'`

If I comment out the `Album` module from the following code (in `/config/application.config.php`):

```
'modules' => array(
    'Application',
    'Album',
),
```

I get to the skeleton application homepage. 
Here is my `/module/Album/Module.php` code:

```
namespace Album;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Album\Model\Album;
use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface {

public function getAutoloaderConfig() {
    return array(
        ’Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader’ => array(
            __DIR__ . ’/autoload_classmap.php’,
        ),
        ’Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader’ => array( ’namespaces’ => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . ’/src/’ . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ), 
    );
}

public function getConfig() {
    return include __DIR__ . ’/config/module.config.php’; 
}

public function getServiceConfig() {
    return array(
        ’factories’ => array(
            ’Album\Model\AlbumTable’ => function($sm) { 
                $tableGateway = $sm->get(’AlbumTableGateway’); 
                $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            ’AlbumTableGateway’ => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get(’Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter’);
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet(); $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                return new TableGateway(’album’, $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            }, 
        ),
    ); 
}
}
```

And here is my `module.config.php` code in `/module/Album/config/`:

```
return array(
’controllers’ => array(
    ’invokables’ => array(
        ’Album\Controller\Album’ => ’Album\Controller\AlbumController’,
    ),
),

’view_manager’ => array( 
    ’template_path_stack’ => array(
        ’album’ => __DIR__ . ’/../view’,
    ),
),

'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/album[/][:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id' => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),'
);
```

I have read through a few people who have ran in to similar situations, but their issues were due to  misspelled/incorrectly named classes. I don't see anything wrong with my code (even went as far as copying/pasting directly from tutorial).

Can someone give me some suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Try updating your `composer` file.

Comment: @KunalDethe as in adding something to the composer file or running the composer update command?

Comment: I created a new skeleton application to try this again and I'm having the same issue. Is it something wrong in the tutorial? I'd be surprised but I really don't know what else it could be

Comment: Try installing the skeleton via `git clone` from [https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) and `composer install/update` from http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

Comment: @KunalDethe just got around to trying this out. Unfortunately I ran in to the same issue.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, and the solution was to start every .php file with `<?php`
This is not clear in the tutorial (if you just copy the code from there), and it was the reason I was getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason i could see is that you should replace all `’` with normal single quotes `'`.
using `’` can results in unexpected behaviors.

Comment: I think that might have just been a copy/paste issue. I replaced all of them and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I came across someone who said the directory structure was wrong, but they didn't say what the correct structure is supposed to be. The screenshot above is exactly what is in the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the tutorials module.config.php file.
Change `'id'     => '[0-9]+',`
to `'id'     => '[0-9]*',`
+ means one or more digits. If you just call http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/album/ there is no digit in the url so the rewriterule doesn't match. Change from + to * (0 or more)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, my issue and solution were

the very first command in the tutorial is:

```
php composer.phar create-project --stability="dev" zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install
```

It was cut off my screen so I copy/pasted the command to the command line without reading the end. So my app directory structure included a directory ./path/to/install where all of the installation files were, including application.config.php.

**Moving everything in /path/to/install/ to the root directory of the app allowed Zend to find the Album module.**

Note: /path/to/install/module contains the album module but will fail if you do

```
mv ./path/to/install/* .
```

so be sure to move the Application module at /path/to/install/module into app_root_dir/module/.

Answer (score 0):

You can check composer.json weather include the following:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
        "Album\\": "module/Album/src"
    }
 },
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check your Module::getConfig() ,
 and play with :
`return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';`
   I have added '../' prefix and it works well .